# Downgrade of kernel fails

Tags: kernel, gcc

I try to use older kernel 3.x with ubuntu 16.04 LTS.
But It seems to be a challenge:
1. on using the default gcc (gcc5):

```
include/linux/compiler-gcc.h:103:30: fatal error: linux/compiler-gcc5.h: No such file or directory
```

2. So I installed gcc-4.8 and tried:

   sudo make CC="gcc-4.8"

and I get:

`update-initramfs: Generating /boot/initrd.img-3.11.1-amd64 E: intel-microcode: unsupported kernel version!`

I tried anyway the install, but it fails at boot:

```
Booting the kernel. <- no more prints
```

I use x86_64 and vanilla kernels 3.11.1, yet it fails to boot with kernel. Actually there are no logs in startup on kernel start.

I haven't find a lot of information about this error, or how to solve it.

Can anyone help?

Comment: Probably not solvable. The kernel version is too old and can't possibly work in 16.04. Why do you think you need it? Maybe there's a better solution.

Comment: I have a need to use a commercial library (.so) in board which says that it supported on up to 3.11.x, (I actually tried to use the library with later version and it failed)

Comment: Unfortunately there's no currently supported Ubuntu release with that kernel version. Even the about to expire 14,04 originally come with 3.13.

Comment: fyi:  Ubuntu 12.04 ESM uses (or used) 3.2; but it's off-topic here  (so if you must have it, it may be an option for you to look up if you're willing to go that route..)

Answer (score 2):

Rather than compiling a kernel, you can use a pre-compiled version released by Ubuntu. `3.16` kernel chain is supported and it might suit your needs.

In your browser address bar paste this: `http://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/`.

- Use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd> to bring up search.
- Use `3.16` as a search string.
- Tap <kbd>PgDn</kbd> key until the screen changes to the image below.

[image: kernel 3.16 index.png]

Notice how `3.16.60` was just compiled on November 6, 2018 by the Ubuntu Kernel Farm. Click on `3.16.60` link and this screen appears:

[image: kernel 3.16.60 download.png]

Click the links under AMD64 to download:

- linux-headers-3.16.60-031660_3.16.60-031660.201810220732_all.deb
- linux-headers-3.16.60-031660-generic_3.16.60-031660.201810220732_amd64.deb
- linux-image-3.16.60-031660-generic_3.16.60-031660.201810220732_amd64.deb

Change to your downloads directory:

```
cd ~/Downloads
```

Keep repeating command until all three files are downloaded with right size:

```
$ ll *.deb
-rw-rw-r-- 1 rick rick  9064576 Nov 12 16:40 linux-headers-3.16.60-031660_3.16.60-031660.201810220732_all.deb
-rw-rw-r-- 1 rick rick   693010 Nov 12 16:39 linux-headers-3.16.60-031660-generic_3.16.60-031660.201810220732_amd64.deb
-rw-rw-r-- 1 rick rick 54562272 Nov 12 16:40 linux-image-3.16.60-031660-generic_3.16.60-031660.201810220732_amd64.deb
```

Install the kernel files for `3.16.60`:

```
sudo dpkg -i *.deb
Selecting previously unselected package linux-headers-3.16.60-031660.
(... SNIP ...)
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of linux-image-3.16.60-031660-generic:
 linux-image-3.16.60-031660-generic depends on module-init-tools (>= 3.3-pre11-4ubuntu3); however:
  Package module-init-tools is not installed.

dpkg: error processing package linux-image-3.16.60-031660-generic (--install):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Errors were encountered while processing:
 linux-image-3.16.60-031660-generic
```

**OH OH** There is a dependency problem. Install missing module:

```
$ sudo apt install module-init-tools
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  module-init-tools
0 upgraded, 1 newly installed, 0 to remove and 15 not upgraded.
1 not fully installed or removed.
Need to get 2,372 B of archives.
After this operation, 18.4 kB of additional disk space will be used.
Get:1 http://ca.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/universe amd64 module-init-tools all 22-1ubuntu5.1 [2,372 B]
Fetched 2,372 B in 0s (7,745 B/s)             
Selecting previously unselected package module-init-tools.
(Reading database ... 346572 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../module-init-tools_22-1ubuntu5.1_all.deb ...
Unpacking module-init-tools (22-1ubuntu5.1) ...
Setting up module-init-tools (22-1ubuntu5.1) ...
Setting up linux-image-3.16.60-031660-generic (3.16.60-031660.201810220732) ...
Running depmod.
update-initramfs: deferring update (hook will be called later)
Examining /etc/kernel/postinst.d.
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postinst.d/apt-auto-removal 3.16.60-031660-generic /boot/vmlinuz-3.16.60-031660-generic
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postinst.d/dkms 3.16.60-031660-generic /boot/vmlinuz-3.16.60-031660-generic
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postinst.d/initramfs-tools 3.16.60-031660-generic /boot/vmlinuz-3.16.60-031660-generic
update-initramfs: Generating /boot/initrd.img-3.16.60-031660-generic
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postinst.d/pm-utils 3.16.60-031660-generic /boot/vmlinuz-3.16.60-031660-generic
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postinst.d/unattended-upgrades 3.16.60-031660-generic /boot/vmlinuz-3.16.60-031660-generic
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postinst.d/update-notifier 3.16.60-031660-generic /boot/vmlinuz-3.16.60-031660-generic
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postinst.d/zz-update-grub 3.16.60-031660-generic /boot/vmlinuz-3.16.60-031660-generic
Generating grub configuration file ...
    (... SNIP ...)
done
```

**AFTER** missing module is installed, kernel `3.16.60` installation carries on where it left off.

---

Booting with `3.16.60` works OK for me but I loose:

- Kernel features for NVMe M.2 SSD Gen 3.0 x 4 suspend / resume.
- Kernel features to set laptop display brightness to last setting.
- nVidia display driver features.
- Support for Thunderbolt Type C DPI to HDMI converter is lost.
- Grub overrides are needed to avoid login loop. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd> needed to access console.

Answer (score 0):

I faced the error below due to package dependencies.

```
module-init-tools (>= 3.3-pre11-4ubuntu3) but it is not going to be installed
```

If the kernel is new build kernel, then you can't get all packages. That's why you are getting this error.

Steps to solve:

1. First you change the content of /etc/sources.list with respective sources file; you just search the file like sources.list  in google.
2. `sudo apt-get update`
3. Install the dependency example: `sudo apt-get install module-init-tools`